# CACHEBUSTING: adding versioning query string to PDF.JS causes canvas tag/thumbnails to not render

Tags: javascript, pdf, canvas, haml, pdf.js

We have recently started adding version strings to our JavaScript files.  A bug has surfaced regarding PDF.JS.

There is a page, REPORTS.
User picks options, reports are shown on the page, each one has a preview image created by PDF.JS using the CANVAS tag.

When PDF.JS is loaded via a script tag, NO version string, everything works. (Technically we're using HAML, like so %script{:type=>'text/javascript', :src=>url_for('/go-get-em-woof/pdf.js')}

When we use the versioning functionality, which renders something like 
< script type='text/javascript' src='/whos-a-good-boy/pdf.js?version=local2653414362456'>< /script>, 
no preview images, no canvas tag at all.

Has anyone seen this before?  It's got us stumped.

Comment: edited to fix formatting issue.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the pdf.js file we were using to the newest version resolved this issue.  So far it seems to be playing nice with the code we have written, and no refactoring was needed.  Still no idea why the old file failed, doesn't matter anymore.